# overwrite canBecomeFirstResponder cause crash in viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

i need to use `UIMenuController` in my `viewController` and overwrite the `canBecomeFirstResponder` method.

```lang-cxx
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Currently, this causes a crash when I enter the `viewController`.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution to fix this issue because I have a property var named `inputView`. When I change the name to `bottomInputView` everything is ok!

I've to search for an answer but I cannot find a solution.
Does anyone know why this is happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any log messages in Xcode’s console? Can you post the crash log (the start and the crashed thread’s info should be enough)

Answer (score 0):

`inputView` is a property of UIResponder.

`canBecomeFirstResponder` is also a property of UIResponder.

You can see the explanation of `inputView` in the document:

`// Called and presented when object becomes first responder. 
   Goes up the responder chain.`

If you rewrite the inputView, it will cause conflicts with `responder chain.`